# How can I add a 2D matrix in R as a dataframe variable?

Tags: r, matrix, dataframe

First, I should mention that I only started looking into R yesterday to use the PLS library. I imported my data from MATLAB with 'R.matlab' library.
One of my matrices I managed to insert to a dataframe quite easily since it was a 1D vector. It showed as

> my_1d_matrix  ...  num [1:205, 1] 124 138 38 76 155 ...

So, I did this:

```
> df <- data.frame(x = my_1d_matrix)
```

My other matrix however is **205x4096**. And it shows like this in my workspace:

> my_2d_matrix ... Large list (205 elements, 6.5 Mb)

How can I insert this as my second variable in the same dataframe? I am actually trying to copy the gasoline dataset from pls library, which has 'octane' as one variable and 'NIR' (60x401 matrix) as the second one. Then it is easy to perform pls-regression.

I want my 205x4096 matrix to be in the same format as the one given by:

```
> str(gasoline$NIR)
```

which is:

```
>AsIs [1:60, 1:401] -0.050193 -0.044227 -0.046867 -0.046705 -0.050859 ...
 - attr(*, "dimnames")=List of 2
  ..$ : chr [1:60] "1" "2" "3" "4" ...
  ..$ : chr [1:401] "900 nm" "902 nm" "904 nm" "906 nm" ...
```

So the end result should be a dataframe similar to 'gasoline', where the *first* variable is **my_1d_matrix** and the *second* one is **my_2d_matrix**.

Comment: Try `as.data.frame(my_2d_matrix)`

Comment: For me a "variable" is always a vector. If you want to keep the 205x4096 structure of `my_2d_matrix` it should be sufficient to write `df2 <- data.frame(my_2d_matrix)`.

Comment: Please read my edited last sentence. I tried `new1 <- data.frame(x = my_1d_matrix, y = df2)` and `new2 <- data.frame(x=my_1d_matrix, y=as.data.frame(my_2d_matrix))` but I got an error of arguments imply differing number of rows: 205, 4096

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently your data is read into a list, i.e. your 2d matrix and the response variable is a matrix. To put both into a data frame you can try:

```
myData <- data.frame(y = my_1d_matrix)
myMat <- matrix(0,205,4096)
for(i in 1:205){
  myMat[i,] <- matrix(unlist(my_2d_matrix[[i]]),1,4096)
}
myData <- cbind(myData,myMat)
```

Now you should be able to call `plsr`:

```
myModel <- plsr(y ~ ., ncomp = 10, data = myData)
```

The dot `.` just means *use all the variables*, because there are no names specified in the `myData` data frame, which probably have names as a numeric.

If this doesn't work, then it is most likely because `my_2d_matrix[[i]]` contains something more then just a numeric vector.

You might want to specify the names of the variables in the data frame, the first column is the response, and the rest are the ones from your large matrix.

Comment: Worked like a charm. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

To embed a matrix "as is" in a data-frame, you have to use `I`:

```
> dim(data.frame(x=1:3, y=array(1:9, c(3,3))))
[1] 3 4
> dim(data.frame(x=1:3, y=I(array(1:9, c(3,3)))))
[1] 3 2
> data.frame(x=1:3, y=I(array(1:9, c(3,3))))$y
     [,1] [,2] [,3]
[1,]    1    4    7
[2,]    2    5    8
[3,]    3    6    9
```

That said embedding a matrix in a data-frame is a bad idea.

Comment: Why is it bad exactly? The pls dataset 'gasoline' is using this embedded matrix and there's official documentation about it. There must be a way to transform the "Large list .." into a matrix. I tried `newdf <- data.frame(x=my_1d_matrix, y = I(my_2d_matrix))`, but it turned y into many `list(c(3.12441, -5125125 ....))` items.

Comment: @kalfasyan Yes, if `my_2d_matrix` isn't a matrix then you have to convert ot to a matrix first, obviously, e.g. `array(unlist(my_2d_matrix), dim=...)`. I said it's a bad idea because some functions will assume that the elements of a data-frame are vectors, so I would avoid it unless I had a very good reason.